# Laravel 5.2, how to query all Foos that have a belongs_to Bar where bar_id is in bar_ids_array

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have som Foos that belong to Bars through a belongs_to joins table.  foo_bar.

I have an array of bar_ids and I want to find all Foos that have a bar_id in the array of bar_ids.

$Foos = \App\Foo::with('bar')->where('bar_id', $barIDs)->get();

that is what I am trying now.  I have tried a few joins but haven't been able to pull this simple query off.

Schema thats relevant:

foo_bar: foo_id, bar_id

this is based on: [BelongsTo](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)

Basically my Foo belongsTo Bar and my Bar belongstoMany Foo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add query constraints for the eager loading query:

`$Foos = \App\Foo::with(['bar' => function ($query) use ($barIDs) {
        $query->whereIn('bar_id', $barIDs)
    }])
    ->get();`

The second way is to make join on your query with pivot table `foo_bar`:

`$Foos = \App\Foo::with('bar')
        ->select('foo.*')
        ->join('foo_bar', 'foo_bar.foo_id', '=', 'foo.id')
        ->whereIn('foo_bar.bar_id', $barIDs)->get();`